# how to find all locations of a sub matrix of the given matrix?But the same cannot be on a image?

Tags: matlab

i want to store all locations of a sub matrix from given matrix...

For example:
given matrix:
zzz =

```
17    24     1     8    15
23     5     7    14    16
 4     6    13    20    22
10    12    19    21     3
11    18    25     2     9
```

lets i want to find locations of submatrix:

kkk =

```
 5     7    14    16
 6    13    20    22
12    19    21     3
18    25     2     9
```

I tried 
[i,j] = ind2sub(size(zzz),find(ismember(zzz,kkk)))

I get proper values in i and j matrix.

But if this 'zzz' is replaced by some dicom image and if 'kkk' is small part that image, in this situation i am not getting desirable i and j values??? somebody help me out???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should modify the line you wrote according to your matrix dimensions. for example, if DICOM images are 3D matrices, then:

```
  [i,j,k] = ind2sub(size(zzz),find(ismember(zzz,kkk)))
```

or

```
 [i,j] = ind2sub(size(zzz),find(ismember(zzz(:,:,k),kkk)))
```

can answer you issue.

If they are 4D arrays you need to act accordingly...

Comment: my dicom image dimensions is shown in this way '<1181x1815x3 double>'?? will above code will work for it???

Comment: just implement: `[i,j,k] = ind2sub(size(zzz),find(ismember(zzz,kkk)))` where `zzz` and `kkk` have the relevant variable names

Comment: not only on dicom it is not working with .jpg image too...
clear all
close all
orig = imread('1.jpg');
Y= double(orig);
figure(1), imshow(Y,[]),title('orignal image');
[b,a]=getpts; b=round(b(1)); a=round(a(1)); 
x1=a-10;x2=a+10;
y1=b-10;y2=b+10;
crop=double(Y(x1:x2,y1:y2));
zzz = crop;
a=4; b=4;
x1=a-1;x2=a+2;
y1=b-1;y2=b+2;
kkk= zzz(x1:x2,y1:y2)
  [i,j] = ind2sub(size(zzz),find(ismember(zzz,kkk))); please find what is wrong in it???